# Kotlin Any - Double missmatch

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to pass arrays that can store value of Double, Int, Long or etc.

```
val input = arrayOf(1.3, 4.5)
val output = arrayOf(3) // Error Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is Array<Int> but Array<Any> was expected

magic(input, output)

fun magic(input: Array<Any>, output: Array<Any>) {
  // Do the magic
}
```

What type of parameters I have to use to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`Number`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-number/index.html)

```
fun magic(input: Array<Number>, output: Array<Number>) {
  // Do the magic
}

val input = arrayOf<Number>(1.3, 4.5)
val output = arrayOf<Number>(3)
magic(input, output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, you could utilize the `Number` class. The documentation on the Kotlin website states that - `Number` is a "Superclass for all platform classes representing numeric values"

You could modify the `magic` function as follows -

```
fun magic(input: Array<Number>, output: Array<Number>) {
   // Do the magic
}
```

Then, invoke the function by constructing the required parameters to the function -

```
val input = arrayOf<Number>(1.3, 4.5)
val output = arrayOf<Number>(3)

magic(input, output)
```

Comment: It seems like you got yours a bit after mine, and it's almost the same, feel free to edit mine if you think you can add something to it